# Monitor API requests using GA 3.4 api with basic credentials

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using the v3 beta api and a service account I'm able to monitor the number of requests I'm making towards GA. Using GA 2.4 api and basic crendentials username/password I can access the API too, but I'm not able to see the number of requests anywhere.
Is there a way to monitor requests for api 2.4 too?

Comment: Have you checked in google apis console.   Its been a while but if  i remember corectly it should still log it there.

Comment: yes it's not in there

Comment: I think thats strange i have an app that doesnt even use there dll's.  It creates all the links itself and its loging there.  Might be a bug in the new apis console, it doesnt display stuff the same as the old apis console does.